# spring bindingresult manytoone LazyInitializationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I use form binding in connection with spring and hibernate. This works well for all input fields which are POJOs.

I have one `@ManyToOne` relation in my model and if I enter a correct value for this dropdown input field, but some other input field has an error in the bindingresult I get an Exception Session/Entity Manager is closed but when I debug I see a com.sun.jdi.InvocationException where my object(country) should link to my object(certificate).

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/processForm", produces = "text/plain;charset=UTF-8")
public String processForm(@Valid @ModelAttribute("sdcertificate") SDCertificate theCertificate,
        BindingResult theBindingResult,
        Model theModel,
        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes,
        @RequestParam("country") int id_country) {

    System.out.println("Binding result: " + theBindingResult + "\n\n\n\n");

    session = factory.getCurrentSession();

    /***** Validation of user input *****/

    if (theBindingResult.hasErrors()) {

        /***** Begin - User Feedback with RedirectAttributes *****/

        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("success", false);

        /***** End - User Feedback with RedirectAttributes *****/

        return "main";
    }
```

When the BindingResult has an error I get the error mentioned. I will paste more code on demand. I want to keep it as simple as possible to read.

This is the output when my Controller tries to create the model.

```
Type Exception Report Message org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: selfservice.Country.certificate, could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Here you can see the database schema. To get the big picture.
[DB Schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gd3VU.png)